# random css position jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random

using math.random, I can position the div to the left, randomly. But i need set the "left" and "right" positions randomly.

```js
jQuery('#popup-container').css({'left' : (Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 3) + '%'})
```

```html
<div id="popup-container" style="background:red;width:30px; height:30px;"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Example, in attribute ".css({left", have an randon with "left or right". An array with these positions. how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply make an array and push 'left' and 'right' into it.

```
var positions = [];
positions.push('left');
positions.push('right');
```

Now, use Math.random for selecting the index for positions array.

```
 jQuery('#popup-container').css(positions[Math.floor(Math.floor(Math.random()%2))], (Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 3) + '%')
```

Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: Thank you Spids :D 
But the code is giving syntax error, did I do something wrong?

Comment: No, maybe I wrote a wrong syntax :D

Give me a min, I hadn't tested that. I'll test it and edit it ;)

Comment: Made the required changes. Please review now

Comment: :) :) :) :) :) :)